# Cannot SVN commit since last windows 10 update

Tags: windows, svn, windows-10

I just restarted after the big windows 10 update ("anniversary update"). From then, I can update with SVN but not commit (in Tortoise or in Webstorm, it keeps working...)

Any one had the same / and a solution?

Note: I reinstalled Tortoise and disabled the windows firewall with no success.

Comment: You should define "I can't update". Do you get any errors?

Comment: From Tortoise, doing "SVN Update" works fine. But "SVN commit" doesn't : the window opens, but it doesn't respond. From Eclipse, I can commit (but Eclipse has a dedicated driver).

Comment: which TSVN version do you use?

Comment: The last one (1.9.4)

Comment: Some users seeing an authentication issue after updating to the Windows 10 Anniversary update. Any version of Tortoise SVN, even from command line. Unspecified authentication errors. Re-install does nothing to fix. Those users having this issue are seeing the Windows Security login prompt when trying to login, instead of the SVN login prompt. Can't figure out why.